# Windows XP install button disabled

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I want to install Windows XP on an Asus laptop with a hidden partition that contains Vista. When I boot the laptop from my XP CD, I can do everything except install it. I get similar behavior when I try to install XP while running Vista. I insert the CD, autorun starts and the install button is disabled.

I've never seen this happen on other computers. How can I enable the install button?